# Angular datatables showing error "cannot read property aDatasort of undefined" when call after HTTP response

Tags: angular, datatables

I am newbie to angular and tried to show datatables in angular after getting http response. Below is my piece of code from component file which showing the 
error

> Typeerror :cannot ready property aDataSort undefined

```
export class SmartComponent implements OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  adunits: any[];
  constructor(private queryConnectorService: QueryConnectorService) { }
   ngOnInit() {
   this.queryConnectorService.getCategory().subscribe((mdata: any[]) => {
    // console.log(mdata)
    this.adunits = mdata;
    this.insertData(this.adunits);
  });    
 }

  insertData(result?: any) {  
   this.dtOptions = {
    data: result,
    columns: [
    { title: 'categoryName', "data": "categoryName" },
    ]
   };
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you able to get the data from the service? `console.log(mdata)` it seems the response is undefined when you are setting `this.dtOptions` .

Comment: yes data is coming

Comment: I got this link with the same problem having workable solution https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/980

thanks